# samza container are failing

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-samza

Hello my samza job containers are failing frequently due to following **errors :**

> Exception from container-launch. Container id: container_1540535314451_0141_01_000021 Exit code: 1 Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538) at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455) at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

can someone help me out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Check the log under `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/[application-id]/[container-id]/` to know more about your problem.